# Elixir Pheonix route unable to find appropriate module/function (module not avilable)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Using the default generated controller, I'm getting the following warning. I also received the warning when tinkering with adding another route. Clearly I'm doing something incorrectly, but it is not obvious from the error message.

```bash
warning: HelloWeb.HelloWeb.PageController.init/1 is undefined (module HelloWeb.HelloWeb.PageController is not available or is yet to be defined)
  lib/hello_web/router.ex:26: HelloWeb.Router.__checks__/0
```

My search results indicate there is generally a mismatch between the controller module name being used in the router, vs the one actually defined, but if that is the case I am unable to detect the difference.

###### Router (router.ex)

```
defmodule HelloWeb.Router do
  alias HelloWeb.PageController
  use HelloWeb, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_live_flash
    plug :put_root_layout, html: {HelloWeb.Layouts, :root}
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
    plug :fetch_current_user
  end

  scope "/", HelloWeb do
    pipe_through :browser

    # I should note that this line produces the following warning in VSCode using the Phoenix extension
    # "HelloWeb.HelloWeb.PageController.init/1 is undefined (module HelloWeb.HelloWeb.PageController is not available or is yet to be defined)"
    get "/", PageController, :home
  end
```

###### Controller (controllers/page_controller.ex)

```
defmodule HelloWeb.PageController do
  use HelloWeb, :controller

  def home(conn, _params) do
    # The home page is often custom made,
    # so skip the default app layout.
    render(conn, :home, layout: false)
  end
end
```

What stands out to me here is that the warning refers to `HelloWeb.HelloWeb.PageController` though the module is named `HelloWeb.PageController`. I don't know the cause of the discrepancy, or even if it is related to the actual issue.

- Why is this code generating a warning?
- Why does the warning complain about the lack of an `init/1` function?
- Why is the module name in the warning longer than the module name defined in the controller file?

EDIT: Based on the helpful solution below, I discovered that the VSCode ElixirLS extension inserts aliases by default if required, which then breaks the way Phoenix handles routing. This can be disabled in the extension settings:

[image]

The downside is that disabling this seems to break autocomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the [scoping of the router](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#module-scopes-and-resources). When you do `scope "/", HelloWeb`, your router knows to look for controllers under the `HelloWeb.` prefix. So, you don't need to alias your controllers. By adding the alias, your router is duplicating the `HelloWeb` part of the module's name, as you can see on the warning.

So:

1. The warning is generated because the router is inferring the wrong name because of the alias that was added.
2. `init/1` is the function that gets called when spawning new processes, so your router is probably trying to spawn a module at `HelloWeb.HelloWeb.PageController`, but since that module doesn't exist with the double `HelloWeb`, it fails to find it and call its `init/1` function.
3. Just because of the combination of the way that module names are inferred and the presence of the alias.

Comment: This was the issue. Some experimentation revealed the VSCode ElixirLS extension "helpfully" inserts the alias be default. Thanks for your help!